# How does permanency work with spells like arcane sight?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

To be more specific if a wizard had used permanency on himself to constantly have arcane sight would the spell enchant his eyes or would it affect his whole body?

To be even more specific, I have the *Flesh Grafting* feat, our wizard recently passed away and we cannot revive him because we are in the Underdark. We don't have a cleric so I was thinking of gouging out his eyes and grafting them on some other party member. Possibly to his backup character.

Comment: I can't find the feat Flesh Grafting. Can you link to it?

Comment: (I know that you're resistant to linking, but selecting the text, clicking the chain link icon, and inputting the URL of the material is fairly painless. You can even link to things manually by surrounding the text with brackets (i.e. `[` then `]`) and—after the closing bracket and *without* a space between, surrounding the URL with parentheses (i.e. `(` then `)`). Manual links like the latter even work in [comments](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).)

Comment: Do you mean http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/fleshwarper-item-creation/ when you refer to fleshgraft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## By raw, No.

As Joel stated, the target of the spell is not a specific body part.

## But....

It is rare that the listed target of a spell is say, "an arm"  or "an eye" or , "a head" but often spells still affect those specific parts, and it makes sense to me that the magic would be concentrated there. Permanency does last into death as well, and will return when revived. It may be possible to either transfer the enchantment, (Gm Fiat, probably some sort of spell research.) Or if the gm is willing, your suggestion is probably something I would allow, in part due to the wording of the spell arcane sight stating it makes you eyes glow, to me implying it concentrates the magic there. Requiring high heal or survival checks to remove the eyes, and keep the magic in tact. Defiling your friends corpse, also not an act of good. Alignment hit should be expected. Both of these methods are GM discretion. Table results may vary

Answer (score 6):

#### No

The target (and thus the thing under the subject of the spell) is *you*. So it's not just the caster's eyes, but his whole body or self.